# How to hide x-axis in lattice R

Tags: r, lattice

How to hide x-axis (xlim?) in lattice xyplot?

Normally with plot that would be:

```
hist(rnorm(10,0,2), axes=F)
```

And also global solution would be great, since I have quite few plots. I'm using the gridExtra package:

```
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,plot3, ncol=3)
```

This for instance allows to hide `xlab, ylab, main.`

```
pl = list(plot1,plot2,plot3)
do.call(grid.arrange, lapply(pl, update, xlab="", ylab="", main=""))
```

Sample data just in case:

```
Data <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10,2,2),y=rnorm(10,3,3),z=rexp(10,2))
plot1 <- xyplot(x~y, Data, xlab="name", ylab="name", main="title")
plot2 <- xyplot(z~y, Data, xlab="name", ylab="name", main="title")
plot3 <- xyplot(z~x, Data, xlab="name", ylab="name", main="title")
```

Hiding globally can be also shown on `print()` on the above or else all this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by "suppress xlim"? Changing the x range of a plot is quite different than blanking out annotations and it really makes no sense to say that it was "suppressed".

Comment: Ok, I mean not to show the xlim on the plot, but in fact use the xlim setup.

Comment: So I have changed now the description, hope it is clear now. Thx.

Comment: A little out of topic, but to remove the y-axis, this is what I had to do: `scales = list(relation = "free", y = list(draw = FALSE))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
xyplot(1:10~1:10, scales=list(x=list(at=NULL)))
```

you should read the docs in `?xyplot`

Comment: I have read lattice manual, but the xyplot settings are just so extensive that it is like reading novel.

Comment: Actually, I was using 'scales' for fine tuning xlim, but never thought about just setting 'at=NULL' so straightforward now. And of course your solution is applicable globally with the command in my post. Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You could also try

`xyplot(1:10~1:10, scales=list(x=list(draw=FALSE)))`

Comment: This solution works better, at least in the case of `dotplot` with `horizontal=FALSE`, since `dotplot(1:10~1:10, horizontal=FALSE, scales=list(x=list(at=NULL)))` does not suppress the x-axis, but `dotplot(1:10~1:10, horizontal=FALSE, scales=list(x=list(draw=FALSE)))` does.