# Hidding x axis when using stripplot?

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to create a `stripplot` in which the name of my parameters on the x axis are greek letters. It is quite logical then that I want my plot to be label with greek letters and not "theta", "rho" and "tau" subscripts. My strategy is to hide the original labels and plot the greek letters on top. The following example shows what I have tried so far:

```
library(lattice)

data <- data.frame(Parameters=c("theta","rho","tau"),val1=c(1,2,4),val2=c(2,3,4))

png("plot.png")
stripplot(val1 + val2 ~ Parameters, data = data, pch=c(1,2), cex=2,
      scales=list(cex=c(0,1.5)),
      xlab=c(expression(rho),expression(tau),expression(theta)),
      ylab=NULL,
      xaxt='n',

)
dev.off()
```

But this piece of code weirdly eliminates the labels in the y axis too.

Try 1:

[image]

I also followed the advice in [How to hide x-axis in lattice R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498349/how-to-hide-x-axis-in-lattice-r) but the results preserves the names in the x-axis.

Try 2:

[image]

How can I eliminate ONLY the labels on the x-axis without altering the y axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the help page for `?stripplot`, in particular the 
`scales` argument.

> Generally a list determining how the x- and y-axes (tick marks and labels) are drawn.

So use this argument to pass the size and labels argument for the x-axis.

```
stripplot(val1 + val2 ~ Parameters, data = dat, pch=c(1,2), cex=2,
   scales=list(x=list(cex=1.5, 
                      labels=c(expression(rho),expression(tau),expression(theta))
)))
```

This is clunky but would help if you had many x-axis elements.

```
labels=as.expression(sapply(levels(dat$Parameters), function(x)  as.name(x)))
```

or

```
labels=parse(text=as.character(sort(dat$Parameters)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lattice)

data <- data.frame(Parameters=c("theta","rho","tau"),val1=c(1,2,4),val2=c(2,3,4))

png("plot.png")
stripplot(val1 + val2 ~ Parameters, data = data, pch=c(1,2), cex=2,
          scales=list(cex=c(0,1.5)),
          xlab=c(expression(rho),expression(tau),expression(theta)),
          xaxt='n',

)
dev.off()
```

[image]